# How to make a parallel auto-generated .m package from Initialization cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, packages

according to the documentation at `ref/InitializationCell`,

> When you first save a notebook that contains initialization cells, you have the option to make a parallel auto-generated .m package that contains only the contents of the initialization cells. The package is by default automatically updated whenever the initialization cells in the notebook are changed and saved again.

This would be a REALLY NICE feature, because it would give me a beautiful way to document a package in a notebook (instead of just textual code)!

To test it out, I took the documentation a bit literally and created a new notebook with a single initialization cell (with the little vertical-hook cell-bracket initialization-cell giveaway highlighted in yellow and circled in red in the screenshot, here:

[image]

The cell after the initialization cell is supposed to be just a reference to the initialization cell, and, when I evaluate the notebook, voila, there is the expected value.

However, when I now save the notebook, I don't get the advertised "option to make a parallel auto-generated .m package."  Ok, so I make one manually (Save As.../Save As Type.../Mathematica Package .m), no problem, as follows:

[image]

But, of course, this one is not "automatically updated whenever the initialization cells in the notebook are changed and saved again."  Here's the updated notebook:

[image]

but the .m file is not automatically updated.  I would use this feature daily if I could get it to work.  As always, I'll be very grateful for advice, guidance, clues.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This may be set from the Option Inspector (Format->Option Inspector) from this option:

[image]

`Automatic` automatically creates a package.

(to be clear, you need to select `Global Preferences` for this to apply to all your notebooks).

Comment: I'd suggest setting it to `Manual`.   If you set it to `Automatic`, it will automatically create the package every time.  If you set it to `Manual`, it will explicitly ask whether the package should be created the first time the notebook is saved.  If it is set to `None`, it will never create the package.

Comment: Is there something similar for scripts? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170420/534

Answer (score 25):

In case you do not want it to apply for all notebooks (which I prefer), you could
 put an additional line somewhere in your notebook:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], AutoGeneratedPackage -> Automatic]
```

or

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], AutoGeneratedPackage -> Manual]
```

Comment: Hi Rolf. Do you know if it's ok to use this? I liked it a lot but the documentation says: "This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Mathematica system, and is subject to change.".

Comment: Hi Murta. Probably ok. There are only 279 such "not fully integrated" itmes. I doubt that those get ever really deleted. This gives you a list: `nlt = FileNameTake /@ 
   Select[ Select[FileNames["*.nb", $TopDirectory, 99], 
     StringMatchQ[#, "*ReferencePages*"] &],
    FindList[#, 
       "has not been fully integrated into the long-term"] =!= {} &];`

Comment: Nice way to scrap documentations. Tks!

Comment: Length[nlt] gives 247 for Mathematica 10.1. So 30 more!

Comment: Hi @RolfMertig , the exported .m file does not maintain the nice indentation in the .nb file's code. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: @tchronis Not directly, but you can use Wolfram Workbench to format the code. Though I really think complicated programming should not be done in notebooks, but directly in Workbench or the IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: @tchronis you can also use `Code` cells which force you to indent by hand. For block indentation edits I wrote my own code which works at the box level of the cells which I'm happy to share if you want it.

Comment: Is there something similar for scripts? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170420/534