# How to change the default ColorData used in Mathematica's Plot?

Tags: plotting, programming, color, customization, style

This question leads on from the recent question [What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391825/421225)

There it was determined that the default color palette used by `Plot` is *equivalent* to `ColorData[1]` (see the note at the end). This can be changed through the use of the option `PlotStyle`.

My question is how can we make, e.g., the default color palette be `ColorData[3]` **and** have this default survive manual changes to other aspects of the plot styling?

---

So, for example, let's make a list of monomials and some dashing settings

```
fns = Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}];
dash = Table[AbsoluteDashing[i], {i, 1, 6}];
```

Note that the default plot colors survive other choices to styling:

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}], Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> dash]}]
```

[image: default]

The colors in the plot may be changed by locally setting `PlotStyle`, such as

```
Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]]
```

or by setting the default options. Let's do that and run the `GraphicsRow` command again:

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]];
GraphicsRow[{Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}], Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> dash]}]
```

[image: ColorList 3]

Note that the new colors in the default plot style is overwritten by the use of `PlotStyle -> dash`. This can be manually fixed, in this case, with `Transpose[{dash, ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[1 ;; 6]]}]`, but you don't want to do that every time.

Changing the default `PlotStyle` will always have this problem.
You'd expect there to be a default `ColorData` or color scheme setting somewhere,
but I have been unable to find it.

---

Note that running the hack

```
Unprotect[ColorData];
ColorData[1] := ColorData[3]
ColorData[1, a__] := ColorData[3, a]
Protect[ColorData];
```

does not fix the default plot colors.
Which probably means that the default internals of `Plot` does not make an explicit call to `ColorData`...

---

It's also interesting to note that when running a `Trace[Plot[...],TraceInternal -> True]` the colors seem to appear out of nowhere! I looked at such a trace in trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597566/telling-plot-to-style-vector-valued-black-box-functions-in-mathematica) recent SO question related to how Mathematica determines the number of lines and thus colors it needs in a plot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Update August 2014

The **Legacy Solution** below has been corrected to work in recent versions (9 and 10).

At the same time however the introduction of [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotTheme.html) functionality makes my solution largely academic as plot themes are designed to combine in the same manner.  If no existing theme has the desired style you can [create a custom one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121).

This example demonstrates setting new default plot colors as well a custom thickness and these correctly combining with the dashing directives in `PlotStyle`:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Thick5", "Plot"] := 
 Themes`SetWeight[{"DefaultThickness" -> {AbsoluteThickness[5]}}, 
  System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight]

SetOptions[Plot, PlotTheme -> {"DarkColor", "Thick5"}];

fns = Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}];
dash = Table[AbsoluteDashing[i], {i, 1, 6}];

Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> dash]
```

[image]

---

## Legacy Solution

The following updated solution is based on the existing solutions from Janus and belisarius with considerable extension and enhancement.

#### Supporting functions

```
ClearAll[toDirective, styleJoin]

toDirective[{ps__} | ps__] := 
  Flatten[Directive @@ Flatten[{#}]] & /@ {ps}

styleJoin[style_, base_] :=
  Module[{ps, n},
    ps = toDirective /@ {PlotStyle /. Options[base], style};
    ps = ps /. Automatic :> Sequence[];
    n = LCM @@ Length /@ ps;
    MapThread[Join, PadRight[#, n, #] & /@ ps]
  ]
```

#### Main function

`pp` is the list of Plot functions you want to affect.

`sh` is needed to handle pass-through plots like `LogPlot`, `LogLinearPlot`, `DateListLogPlot`, etc.

```
pp = {Plot, ListPlot, ParametricPlot, ParametricPlot3D};

Unprotect /@ pp;

(#[a__, b : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Block[{$alsoPS = True, sh},
     sh = Cases[{b}, ("MessagesHead" -> hd_) :> hd, {-2}, 1] /. {{z_} :> z, {} -> #};
     With[{new = styleJoin[OptionValue[PlotStyle], sh]}, #[a, PlotStyle -> new, b]]
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$alsoPS];
 DownValues[#] = RotateRight[DownValues@#]; (* fix for versions 9 and 10 *)
) & /@ pp;
```

---

### Usage

Now different plot types may be individually styled as follows:

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]];
```

Or in groups (here using `pp` defined above):

```
SetOptions[pp, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]];
```

---

### Examples

`PlotStyle` options are then automatically added:

```
fns = Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}];
dash = Table[AbsoluteDashing[i], {i, 1, 6}];

Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> dash]
```

[image]

---

`Plot[...]` and `Plot[..., PlotStyle -> Automatic]` are consistent:

```
Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}]
Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]
[image]

---

Pass-through plots (those that call `Plot`, `ListPlot` or `ParametricPlot`) can be given their own style:

```
SetOptions[LogPlot, PlotStyle -> ColorData[2, "ColorList"]];

LogPlot[{Tanh[x], Erf[x]}, {x, 1, 5}]
LogPlot[{Tanh[x], Erf[x]}, {x, 1, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Thick}}]
```

[image]
[image]

---

`PlotStyle` handling can be extended to different *Plot* types.

I included `ParametricPlot3D` above as an example:

```
fns = {1.16^v Cos[v](1 + Cos[u]), -1.16^v Sin[v](1 + Cos[u]), -2 1.16^v (1 + Sin[u])};

ParametricPlot3D[fns, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 6},
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image]

---

#### Implementation note

As it stands, resetting `SetOptions[..., PlotStyle -> Automatic]` will revert the colors to the original defaults.  If this behavior is undesirable, the code can be modified to give a different default color, in the manner of Janus' `also` function, upon which my `styleJoin` is clearly based.

Comment: That's really good - it works well/smoothly. How did you find out about the `"MessagesHead"` thing -- that looks pretty obscure. I was really hoping that you'd found some way to use ``System`Private`$PlotStyleFunction``, but never mind. I have two small problems with the code. (1) As you pointed out in @belisarius' answer, changing the colors of the Plot does not effect the colours of the filling. It would be possible to hack this with `FillingStyle` - but not really necessary.

Comment: (2) I find associating a plotting rule with a UpValue on `Rule` a bit perverse. It also leads to the problem that @Sasha pointed out, since `Rule` is too deep for a pattern match to his example. This can be fixed by making a loop that produces a normal `DownValue` for each `h` in `pp`. This can also be designed to fix the problem that Sasha pointed out. Fix this issue and you get the bounty - since it is probably the best "simple" solution that is possible.

Comment: @Simon, re: `"MessagesHead"`, while you had me digging around in the bowels of Plot I found something useful.  I don't know what I was looking at when I commented on belisarius' answer, as Janus' method doesn't handle `FillingStyle` either from what I can tell.  I don't know why I thought it did.  If you would like that to change as well I'd be happy to try.

Comment: @Simon, by the way, I may have to add "I code perverse Mathematica" to my profile. ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Nah, the `FillingStyle` thing is minor. It probably would be the proper default behaviour for it to copy the `Plot` colors, but if it was really important, then that would already be the default behaviour in Mathematica (ie `Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis]` would have a red fill). -- So, just fix point (2) and the money is yours!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It looks fine (+125)! A lot more solid than the previous version. I'm sure that this was some of the hardest 100pts that you've earned. And since your solution built off that of @Janus and @Belisarius,  I feel like they should share in the bounty. **So everyone who has voted up Mr.Wizards answer, go and vote up Janus' and Belisarius' answers!!**

Comment: @Simon, thank you!  The rep points are nice, but the real reward is knowing I helped. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Does this still work in v9? Overriding the `Plot` function(s) doesn't seem to work for me (the default behaviour is not modified).

Comment: It seems (?) this does not work anymore in v9. Can you now confirm? @Janus's answer works but requires active use of also, which is somewhat less elegant?

Comment: @Will I have corrected my (legacy) method to work in version 10.  It should also work in version 9.  For version 10 there is now a better solution however; see the section at the top.

Comment: @chris Please see the comment directly above.

Answer (score 23):

Here is one take on it -- the hard part was estimating how the `PlotStyle` option is turned into a list of directives. I think this works as the internal implementation:

```
canonicalPlotStyle::usage = 
  "Turn a PlotStyle option into the canonical form {_Directive...}";
canonicalPlotStyle[ps_] := Replace[ps, {
   a_List :> (Flatten[Directive @@ Flatten[{#}]] &) /@ a,
   a_ :> {Flatten@Directive[a]}}]
```

Building on `canonicalPlotStyle` it's now just a matter of combining two lists of unequal length:

```
also::usage = 
  "Combines a specified plotstyle with the current defaults as \
  specified by Options.";
also[plotstyle_] := Module[{ps, n},
  ps = canonicalPlotStyle /@ {
     (PlotStyle /. Options[Plot]) /. Automatic :> ColorData[1, "ColorList"],
     plotstyle};
  n = LCM @@ (Length /@ ps);
  Join @@@ Transpose[Flatten[Table[#, {n/Length[#]}], 1] & /@ ps ]]
```

This does require you to call the function when you plot, but I couldn't see any way around that part:

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]];
GraphicsRow[{Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}], 
  Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> also@dash]}]
```

[image: output from above code]

HTH

Comment: As you can see, I'm using the defaults from `Plot` no matter where `also` is used. It might actually be nicer to use Options associated with `also`. This would also remove any need to fiddle with Options for `Plot`...

Comment: Nice! +1. I think I prefer keeping the options associated with `Plot` (or which ever plotting function you want to use `also` with) so that it behaves as close to normal as possible.  Obviously, it's not quite the answer I'm hoping for (ie a simple setting for a default color scheme), but it's still useful.

Comment: Two small problems. 1) `also` overrides any manually set colors in the plot. This is simply fixed by reversing the order of terms in `ps` putting the locally supplied options last. 2) You need `also` every time you make a plot using a manual `PlotStyle` setting -- a little annoying, but not a deal breaker!

Comment: @Simon -- Thanks for catching the ordering bug. I actually thought it had to be the way I did it, maybe inspired by rules. Will edit above.

Answer (score 11):

This is work in progress, I'm posting it because I'm not sure to be able to finish it, and perhaps someone wants to.

The idea is to combine the wonderful Janus's solution with [this nice trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) to redefine the **Plot[ ]** standard behavior.

The program below works for a large subset of the help page for Plot[ ], but fails for two or three. The code is not tidied up, just a draft with leftovers.

```
Unprotect[Plot];
Plot[argsANDopts___] :=
  Block[
    {$inMsg = True, result, also, canonicalPlotStyle, opts, args, 
     optPstyle},

    If[(opts = 
        FilterRules[Cases[{argsANDopts}, _Rule], Options[Plot]]) == {},
     opts = {Axes -> (Axes /. Options[Plot])}];(*Anything not null*)
    args = Cases[{argsANDopts}, Except@_Rule];

    If[(optPstyle = Cases[opts, Rule[PlotStyle, y__] :> y]) == {}, 
     optPstyle = (PlotStyle /. Options[Plot])];

    canonicalPlotStyle[ps_] := 
     Replace[ps, {a_List :> (Flatten[Directive @@ Flatten[{#}]] &) /@ 
         a, a_ :> {Flatten@Directive[a]}}];

    also[plotstyle_] := 
     Module[{ps, n}, 
      ps = canonicalPlotStyle /@ {(PlotStyle /. Options[Plot]) /. 
          Automatic :> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], plotstyle};
      n = LCM @@ (Length /@ ps);
      Join @@@ Transpose[Flatten[Table[#, {n/Length[#]}], 1] & /@ ps]];

    (*Print@opts;
    Print@args;
    Print@optPstyle;
    Print@Evaluate@also[opts];*)
    result = Plot[
      Evaluate@Sequence@@args,
      PlotStyle -> also[optPstyle],
      Evaluate@Sequene@@opts
      ];
    result

    ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg];
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]];
Protect[Plot];
```

samples:

[image]

Does not work for:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

Comment: +1 for still using the magic variable `$inMsg`! I'm overrun at the moment, so will look more carefully at the code on the weekend...

Answer (score 4):

The most likely source of style data, in my opinion, is:

```
System`Private`$PlotStyleFunction[5]
```

```
{{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]},
 {Hue[0.906068, 0.6, 0.6]},
 {Hue[0.142136, 0.6, 0.6]},
 {Hue[0.378204, 0.6, 0.6]},
 {Hue[0.614272, 0.6, 0.6]}}
```

However, using `Unprotect` and changing this function does not effect the desired change in `Plot`.  Perhaps the call is out of reach to normal methods.

Comment: Mr.W: It did look promising - but doesn't actually seem do do anything. Have you looked at `Trace` with `TraceInteral->True`? I discovered `Graphics`PerformanceTuningDump`colors` that way... but it also seems to be/do nothing. Another interesting thing to look at is the output of `DeleteCases[Table[{x, Names[x <> "Color*", IgnoreCase -> True]}, {x, Contexts[]}], {_, {}}] // Column`...  There might be something useful there, but I haven't found it yet (or figured out the right way of using it).

Comment: Mma 7 does not appear to have "Graphics`PerformanceTuningDump`colors`" unless I am doing it wrong.  When you say `$PlotStyleFunction` doesn't do anything, do you mean with regard to `Plot`?  Because it certainly does give the right output on my system.  (editing post to include that...)

Comment: I see, nice! That matches exactly the colors used by `Plot` -- unlike `ColorData[1,"ColorList"]` which is out by 10^-16 in some cases.  ``System`Private`$PlotStyleFunction[n, lst]`` gives a list of styles `n` long where extra styles in `lst` are "Riffled" into it. This behaviour can be easily emulated, but changing `$PlotStyleFunction` (either as a `DownValue` or a pure function `OwnValue`) doesn't seem to make any difference to `Plot`... :(

Comment: @Simon, you see why I was excited, and then disappointed.  I wonder if that actually *is* the right function, but if it is called at a level lower than `DownValues`/`OwnValues` and thereby out of reach.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yep, I see it.  Were you able to get Mma to give you *any* info about ``System`Private`$PlotStyleFunction``? Although it evaluates as in your edit, I couldn't find any `*values` for it and nothing shows up in any trace that I tried -- I think this means that it might be a "kernel function" i.e. built in and compiled into the kernel. This is probably the lower level that you were asking about (although I don't know much about it and could be wrong!!)

Comment: I just tried [this type of trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) to see if ``System`Private`$PlotStyleFunction`` is called when `Plot`ing... it looks like it might not be. Maybe it's just a copy of or a reference to a more basic function that is used by `Plot`?

Comment: @Simon @Mr. Sherlock would be proud of you both :)

Comment: @Simon the text "$PlotStyleFunction" does appear within mathdll.dll.  I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard When searching the string `$PlotStyleFunction` in the *Mathematica*'s directory by Total Commander I have found four files in the "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\7.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\" subdirectories: `{Binaries\Windows-x86-64\mathdll.dll,Binaries\Windows\mathdll.dll,SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\Explore\PlotExplorer.mx,SystemResources\Windows\Explore\PlotExplorer.mx}`. HTH.