# Determining the RGB values of the default plot color

Tags: plotting, color

In Mathematica 7, the default plot color is a purple-like color (although I think it is *not* `Purple`).  Is it possible to use Mathematica to determine the RGB color values of the default plot color?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: This one was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391825/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the default colors can be found in `ColorData[1]`. To obtain the RGB value of the first color you just need to type:

```
ColorData[1, 1]
(* RGBColor[0.2472, 0.24, 0.6] *)
```

To check all subsequent colors just change the *n* in `ColorData[1, n]`.
To obtain the values on the scale 0 to 255:

```
Round[Rescale[Table[ColorData[1, 1][[i]], {i, 3}], {0, 1}, {0, 255}]]
(* {63, 61, 153} *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  So, if (as in other programs) the RGB values are on a scale from 0 to 255, I just need to multiply the Mathematica RGB values by 255?

Comment: @Andrew See update.

Comment: v10.3 `255(List@@ColorData[97,n])`

Answer (score 7):

`ColorData[1,"ColorList"]` gives the full list for the default colour set.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The closest source of the default style colors I could find is this internal function:

```
System`Private`$PlotStyleFunction[3]
```

> ```
> {{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}, {Hue[0.906068, 0.6, 0.6]}, {Hue[0.142136, 0.6, 0.6]}}
> ```

Yielding e.g. the first three style colors.  These as noted by others are exceedingly close to `ColorData[1]`, the function of which is:

```
ColorData[1][[4]]
```

> ```
> (ToColor[Hue[N[FractionalPart[0.67 + (2 (#1 - 1))/GoldenRatio]], 0.6, 0.6],
>   RGBColor] &)[Floor[#1 - 1, 1] + 1] &
> ```

If you are interested in changing the defaults don't miss:

[How to change the default ColorData used in Mathematica's Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/121)

Comment: Since `System\`Private\`$PlotStyleFunction` returns HSB values as opposed to RGB values, if you want to see the RGB values, do this: `ColorConvert[#, RGBColor] & /@ Flatten[System\`Private\`$PlotStyleFunction[3]]`.

Answer (score 3):

The default color is `Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]`

Comment: How did you determine this or where did you find this documented? -- Thx

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to convert those values to RGB values used in many paint programs?

Comment: Also, it seems that in some programs (for example, Microsoft Word 2003), HSL values go from 0 to 255, not 0 to 1 as in Mathematica.  I guess, then, I should just multiply by 255 and round to the nearest integer?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, certainly.