# What's the default color function for BarChart, PieChart?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, charts, default

If one increases the number of colored items in a `BarChart` or `PieChart` one can see that its color scheme is based on a gradient of some sort:

```mma
charts[n_] := Module[
  {data = ConstantArray[1, n]
   , opts = Sequence[
     ImageSize -> Tiny
     , ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None]
     , PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
     , ImagePadding -> 0
     , Axes -> False
     ]
   }, {BarChart[{data}, opts], PieChart[data, opts]}
  ]
Column[charts /@ {2, 5, 100}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Basically, the two colors seen for the case *n* = 2 are the ends of the gamut.  Assigning colors to *n* > 2 items amounts to picking *n* - 2 additional colors evenly spaced between these two ends.

---

I stared for a while at the [available gradients](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html#52253903) looking for one that matched [image: Mathematica graphics], but I can't spot it.

---

Does anyone know the default color function for these chart types?

Comment: The old colour scheme worked like this: for `n = 100; Lighter[#1, 0.66] & /@ 
 Table[Hue[0.6 (1 - i)], {i, 0, 1, 1/(n - 1)}]` - ref. [Link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42204/363), but I don't know the formula for the new colours.

Comment: the indexed scheme `ColorData[111]` resembles those colors, however they are not indexed sequentially to produce a gradient in an obvious way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirming @Carl's finding without `Trace`:

```mma
Blend[Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 0.2], #1] &
```

This is obtained as the setting of the suboption `"ChartDefaultStyle"` for the default `PlotTheme` for `PieChart`:

```mma
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, PieChart]
```

> ```
> {GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]],   
>  LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], FontFamily -> "Arial"},   
>  Method -> {"ChartDefaultStyle" ->   
>    (Blend[Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 
>     0.2], #1] &), "DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic, 
>  "DefaultChartBaseStyle" -> EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0, 0.5]],
> "DefaultPlotStyle" -> Automatic}}
> ```

```mma
System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
% // InputForm
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[0.97858, 0.678934, 0.157834], RGBColor[1., 0.43, 0.], 
>  RGBColor[0.73, 0.344, 0.], RGBColor[0.594326, 0.356, 0.653099], 
>  RGBColor[0.374, 0.444, 0.788663]}
> ```

Verifying with a 5-element dataset:

```mma
Row[{ PieChart[{1,1,1,1,1}, ImageSize->300], 
   PieChart[{1,1,1,1,1}, ImageSize->300, 
   ChartStyle->Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient,.2]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Kuba, thank you so much for the edit. Didn't know  how to typeset the backticks in code environment.

Comment: Well, I didn't do this, I only inserted `<!-- language: lang-mma -->` because something is wrong with highlighting in this topic

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) and guess that [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend) is being used:

```mma
TracePrint[charts[2], _Blend, TraceAction->(Print[InputForm[#]]&)]
```

> HoldForm[Blend[Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 0.2], 0.]]
>
> HoldForm[Blend[{RGBColor[0.982864, 0.7431472, 0.3262672], RGBColor[1., 0.544, 0.2], RGBColor[0.784, 0.47519999999999996, 0.2], RGBColor[0.6754608, 0.4848, 0.7224792], RGBColor[0.4992, 0.5552, 0.8309304]}, 0.]]
>
> ...