# Setting same color for surface and parametric curve

Tags: plotting, color

How can we set the same color for a surface and a 3D parametric curve in version 9? Here is an example below.

```
Show[{Plot3D[-y, {t, -1, 0}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{1, -t, t}, {t, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

More precisely, how can we determine the color of the surface and set it to the black line?

[image: surface and line]

Comment: From your picture, you seem to be using pre-version 10...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it is 9.0

Comment: The thing is... the "color" in that surface is actually just the lights reflecting off the surface. Try adding `Lighting -> "Neutral"` to `Plot3D[]` to see what I mean. Now, since lines do not reflect light...

Comment: Oh, I see now. I tought it was like default curve color and filling color for 2d plots. What is the difference between default curve color and filling color for a 2d plot?

Comment: I think I figured it out by using `Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis][[1]]`. It is `Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]` and `Opacity[0.2], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]` respectively.

Comment: In version 10 onwards, what you ask is reasonable, since the surfaces aren't just white anymore. That color you extracted from `Plot[]` is `ColorData[1, 1]`. (See e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11790).)

Comment: I have Mathematica 10 at my office. I will check it over there.