# Why do Plot and ListPlot use the last PlotStyle when only one thing is plotted?

Tags: plotting, version-9

When a list of `PlotStyle`s is given, `ListPlot` behaves as expected when there are multiple things to plot:

```
ListPlot[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100], 2 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

When there's only one thing to plot, it chooses the *last* `PlotStyle` instead of the first one.

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100], PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Enclosing the single thing to be plotted in `{}` appears to cause things to behave as expected.

```
ListPlot[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

`Plot` shows the same behavior.

This does not appear to happen with the default `PlotStyle`s, but it does happen if you modify the default styles using [this kind of technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/92).

Why is a single plot argument treated as a special case? Can this behavior be changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would venture that when you have the lone function to plot, Mathematica assumes your list of styles should all be applied, and blue is just the one to be applied last. Consider for instance:

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.05], Blue}]
```

[image: big blue points]

What behavior would you expect or want to see instead?

Also consider this:

```
ListPlot[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue}}]
```

Comment: Aha. I thought `Directive` was always required for multiple-word styles. This is a symptom of that not being the case. Thanks.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens certainly using `Directive` is the correct, documented way to do it. Although the meaning of a list of directives without head `Directive` is rather ambiguous as you correctly point out in your question, I suppose some versions are more or less tolerant of such incorrect (but fairly commonly supplied) inputs than others.

Answer (score 2):

I have to wonder what version this is, since trying this on *Mathematica* 8 shows no difference.

Letting

```
dat = {-1, 0, 1/2, 2};
```

I see that

```
ListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

and

```
ListPlot[{dat}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

both produce the same plot, with blue points. Why this is the case might be a bit clearer if we peek into the `InputForm[]`:

```
ListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}] // InputForm
   Graphics[{{{}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6],
             RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
             Point[{{1., -1.}, {2., 0.}, {3., 0.5}, {4., 2.}}]}, {}}},
            {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
             PlotRange -> {{0, 4.}, {-1., 2.}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
             PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

where the bit most important for our purposes is `{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Point[{{1., -1.}, {2., 0.}, {3., 0.5}, {4., 2.}}]}`. Notice the four, yes *four* color directives coming before the `Point[]` object. Doing something similar to `ListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> Blue] // InputForm` gives the important part `{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Point[{{1., -1.}, {2., 0.}, {3., 0.5}, {4., 2.}}]}`.

By now, you should realize why the behavior of making only the last directive apply to the primitive(s) ought to be the case; in the simpler case of `ListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> Blue]`, this allows you to see your points in the color you intended them to be (blue) instead of the default color used by `ListPlot[]`. In the OP's case, the other three colors preceding `RGBColor[0, 0, 1]` and the `Point[]` object are ignored in the final rendering, which is why you see them in blue.

In any event, if you're wondering why your third example turned red, you might want to inspect the `InputForm[]` and do a few comparisons.

Comment: Mine is version 9. It looks like they changed something. The green and blue colors never appear in the `InputForm` of the third example.

Comment: Huh, very interesting. Maybe you should update your question to include this observation. (Use a simpler set of points, tho!)