# Permanently Changing Default Color

Tags: plotting, color

I can't find this answer elsewhere, but is there a way to permanently change the default plot color? In 10 the default plots are orangish and in 9 they were a purple-bluish color. Is there a way to change this default value so that every new notebook has the same color scheme?

I'm not worried about the background or text color, just the plot color.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(4712)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/121)

Comment: `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` should give the pre-10 appearance.

Answer (score 5):

Since you claim "the default plots are orangish", I infer that you are working with `Plot3D`. The coloring of surfaces in a 3D plot can be tricky because there are many options and directives that affect the visible coloring. Some of these options affect the lighting and others the intrinsic coloring.

Let's look at some examples.

**Default lighting and coloring**

```
With[{max = 2}, Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max},
  PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes", "ZMesh"}]]
```

[image: default]

The intrinsic color is yellow, but most of the visible coloring is an effect of the lighting as the following demonstrates.

**Lighting switched to neutral**

```
With[{max = 2}, Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max},
  PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes", "ZMesh"},
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: neutral]

We can choose to dramatically change the visible coloring by changing either the lighting or the intrinsic coloring. Even more complicated things can be done by monkeying with both, but I'm not to go there as this answer is already getting rather long.

**Change the lighting**

```
With[{max = 2}, Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max},
  PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes", "ZMesh"},
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[0.25, 0.5, 1], {0, 0, 3}}}]]
```

[image: blue-light]

**Change the intrinsic color**

```
With[{max = 2},
  Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max},
    PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes", "ZMesh"},
    ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0.25, 0.5, 1] &),
    Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: color_func]

What should you carry away from this little demo? That you should read up on the `Lighting` and the `ColorFunction` options in the Documentation Center and maybe the `PlotTheme` option, too.

**Making the options of choice into defaults**

Suppose you like the look the last plot and want that look to be applied automatically to all `Plot3D` expressions unless explicitly overridden. To obtain this evaluate:

```
SetOptions[Plot3D,
  PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes", "ZMesh"},
  ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0.25, 0.5, 1] &),
  Lighting -> "Neutral"];
```

Now

```
With[{max = 2}, Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max}]]
```

gives

[image: color_func]

Answer (score 2):

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

If you plan to plot several functions simultaneously, you'll need a list of colors, e.g.,

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple}]
```

Comment: All of this can be placed in `init.m` if need be.