# Override a PlotTheme element at the Options level?

Tags: plotting, options, customization, plot-themes

*Edit: I am still using version 10.1; has anything changed by 11.0.1?*

---

Plot properties defined in a Theme override (supersede) properties defined on [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html).

This can be undesirable in a case such as:

```
customLegend = 
  LineLegend[97, {"base 2", "natural", "base 10"}, 
   LegendLabel -> "Logarithms"];

SetOptions[ListPlot, PlotLegends -> customLegend];

ListPlot[{Log2, Log, Log10}[Range@40] // Through,
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
]
```

[image]
( *Where is my legend?* )

To make it explicitly clear if you use the option `PlotTheme -> None` or set `$PlotTheme = None` the legend works as intended.

Considering work-arounds:

- One can make the `Options`-defined legend appear by using `PlotTheme -> None` but that is a heavy-handed solution that loses benefit of Themes.
- One can of course set `PlotLegends -> customLegend` within every `ListPlot` expression but that loses the benefit of a global setting.
- One can [define a custom theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121) with a [prioritizing weight](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87282/121) and use `PlotTheme -> {"legend", "Detailed"}` but the two must be used together: one cannot use `SetOptions[ListPlot, PlotTheme -> "legend"]` and then `PlotTheme -> "Detailed"` within `ListPlot` and have them combine.
- One could use a custom `myListPlot` that gives priority to `Options` settings, e.g. `myListPlot[args___] := ListPlot[args, Options @ myListPlot]`.  This seems to have the least downside of the listed methods but it will not apply to existing `ListPlot` uses without substitution.

What other avenues of approach might one take to this problem?

Comment: One could lobby WRI to do `PlotThemes` right. One could work to get many others to do the same.

Comment: @m_goldberg I do not feel that Plot Themes are done "wrong."  Actually I'm quite happy with them and *egotistically* I like to think of them as an outgrowth of [my own method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4716/121).  However there are certain points such as this that could benefit from improvement.  I'd like to be able to do `SetOptions[ListPlot, PlotLegends -> Priority[customLegend]]` and have it supersede Themes.  I'll code up something like that in a self-answer at some point I think.

Comment: Same in v11.0.0.0.

Comment: The example doesn't work even without `PlotTheme`. It seems like the legends have to be used with every `ListPlot` call. Checked on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Stitch `ListPlot[{Log2, Log, Log10}[Range@40] // Through, PlotTheme -> None]` shows that this *is* caused by the Plot Theme system.

Comment: Who knew! I thought `Automatic` (default for `$PlotTheme`) should not interfere...

Comment: @Stitch The PlotThemes functionality is always active unless you expressly turn it off with `None`.  When you do you find that plots go back to their old colors.  So if you see the new colors in use and you did not manually specify them a Plot Theme is active

Comment: Mr.Wizard, to your 3rd bullet point. How about using an UpValue: `PlotTheme /: Rule[PlotTheme, x_String] := 
 Rule[PlotTheme, {"customLegendTheme", x}]`. This way you don't need to redo your old ListPlot calls.

Comment: @Stitch I think one would not want that rule to fire on every appearance of `PlotTheme`.  How would one restrict that to only being active inside `ListPlot`?

Comment: How about this? `PlotTheme /: Rule[PlotTheme, x_String] := 
 RuleDelayed[PlotTheme, 
  If[MemberQ[Stack[], ListPlot], {"customLegendTheme", x}, x]]`? For complete solution, one would also need to define the `TagSetDelayed` for the `RuleDelayed`

Comment: @Stitch Not a bad idea!  I'll play with that later when I have time. Thank you :-)

Comment: Glad you liked it! It seems like you would have to use `resolvePlotTheme`. The `AddThemeRules` method works very strange -- when you create a custom theme, you can only call it `PlotTheme->"custom"`. If you do as simple as `PlotTheme->{"custom"}`, it doesn't work... `resolvePlotTheme` doesn't have this kind of weird behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example using the original post bullet #3 idea and the discussion in the comment section above (including [custom theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121) and [theme weighting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87282/121)):

First, we define a function that sets options using [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) and [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) and the other one that clears them:

```
ClearAll[robustSetOptions, robustClearOptions];

robustSetOptions[function_, 
  options_?(MatchQ[#, Rule[_, _]] || MatchQ[#, List[Rule[_, _] ...]] &)] := 
 Module[{newTheme = "customTheme"},
  System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[newTheme, ToString@function] :=
    Themes`SetWeight[options, System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight];
  Unprotect[PlotTheme];
  If[UpValues[PlotTheme] =!= {},
   PlotTheme /: Rule[PlotTheme, x_String] =.;
   PlotTheme /: RuleDelayed[PlotTheme, x_String] =.
   ];
  SetOptions[function, PlotTheme -> newTheme];
  Unprotect[PlotTheme];
  PlotTheme /: Rule[PlotTheme, x_String] := 
   RuleDelayed[PlotTheme, 
    If[MemberQ[Stack[], function], {newTheme, x}, {x}]];
  PlotTheme /: RuleDelayed[PlotTheme, x_String] := 
   RuleDelayed[PlotTheme, 
    If[MemberQ[Stack[], function], {newTheme, x}, x]];
  Protect[PlotTheme];
  ]

robustClearOptions[function_] := Module[{},
  If[UpValues[PlotTheme] =!= {},
     Unprotect[PlotTheme];
     PlotTheme /: Rule[PlotTheme, x_String] =.;
     PlotTheme /: RuleDelayed[PlotTheme, x_String] =.;
     Protect[PlotTheme];
     ]
    SetOptions[function, PlotTheme -> $PlotTheme];
  ]
```

Then we can call it to define custom options (applied as a custom theme). Multiple options are possible (in this example there is a custom legend from the OP and the [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html)):

```
ClearAll[g1, g1t, g2, g2t, g1d, g2d, plot1, plot1t, plot2, plot2t];

(* define custom options *)
customLegend = LineLegend[97, {"base 2", "natural", "base 10"}, LegendLabel -> "Logarithms"];
plotTheme = "Detailed";

plot1 := ListPlot[{Log2, Log, Log10}[Range@40] // Through];
plot1t := ListPlot[{Log2, Log, Log10}[Range@40] // Through, PlotTheme -> plotTheme];
plot2 := ListLinePlot[{Log2, Log, Log10}[Range@40] // Through];
plot2t := ListLinePlot[{Log2, Log, Log10}[Range@40] // Through, PlotTheme -> plotTheme];

(* set custom options *)
robustSetOptions[ListPlot, {PlotLegends -> customLegend, AspectRatio -> 1}];
g1 = plot1; (* should see a legend *)
g1t = plot1t; (* should see a legend *)
g2 = plot2; (* should not see a legend *)
g2t = plot2t; (* should not see a legend *)

(* remove custom options *)
robustClearOptions[ListPlot];
g1d = plot1;  (* should not see a legend *)
g2d = plot2;  (* should not see a legend *)

Grid[{
  {"", "robustSetOptions", SpanFromLeft, "default"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "No PlotTheme", "With PlotTheme \"" <> plotTheme <> "\"", SpanFromAbove},
  {"ListPlot", g1, g1t, g1d}, {"ListLinePlot", g2, g2t, g2d}}, 
 Alignment -> {Left, 
   Automatic, {{1, 2} -> Center, {1, 4} -> {Center, Center}, {2, 2} ->
      Center, {2, 3} -> Center, {2, 1} -> Center, {3, 1} -> Center}}, 
 Dividers -> Center]
```

As expected, there is a legend and the graphs are squared when [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)is called with or without the [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) option. Any other function (ilustrated with [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)) is not affected by the options, as they are set only for a specific function ([`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)in this example). After the options are cleared, all functions are back to their default style.

> [image]

As this is a working example, please comment, critique, improve or suggest better ways of implementing it.

Comment: I surely like where you're going with this.  I'll need to play with it a bit when I have time before I know if it will behave as I hope, but +1 for now.