# finding RGBcolors of the default used colored plots

Tags: plotting

When I use of plot in *Mathematica*, this uses of default colors for plotting.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Cot[x], Sinh[x], Cosh[x], Tanh[x], 
Coth[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

How can I find the `RGBColor` of default used color in `Mathematica` in order to utilize manually them in the future (when I want to use `RGBColor` in some purposes)

[image]

Comment: see [What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica 10](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10) and [How to change the default ColorData used in Mathematica's Plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4712/how-to-change-the-default-colordata-used-in-mathematicas-plot)

Comment: Generally, how can I find the properties of a plot about which I don't know any details? I had seen before in SE but I can't remember where I had seen! for example you have a plot which is not plotted by you. but you want to know about its details what command can help you?

Comment: You should ask a new question and add if possible a concrete example of this case.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but I will try much to find my answer, because I will be duplicated in the new question!