# Set colour as default plot-colour

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to set a RGB-colour as a default colour for 3-dimensional plots (I want that the RGB-colour [0.,0.5,1.] will be my default colour) ?
Here a code for example:
`Plot3D[Sin[x^2+y^2]/(x^2+y^2),{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-Pi,Pi},PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0., 0.5, 1.]]`
Thanks very much :)

Comment: Use `SetOptions[Plot3D, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0., 0.5, 1.]];`  Also see: [(4712)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/121)

Answer (score 1):

```
SetOptions[Plot3D, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0., 0.5, 1.]];
Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y^2]/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```