# define new colors

Tags: plotting, color

Is there any direct way to use HTML color codes as [here](http://html-color.org/10D010) for plot command of *Mathematica*. For example we can use of `\definecolor{xyz}{HTML}{desired code}` to use of those color codes in the `latex`. How can we define a desired color by using HTML color codes for plotting in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try pressing Control-=, then entering `#fa6`. Or just `RGBColor["#fa6"]`.

Comment: `RGBColor["#10D010"]` works straight out of the box

Comment: I do find decimal much easier to read than hex though ...

Comment: I didn't notice this had the `plotting` tag when I voted it as a duplicate, if I was wrong let me know.

Comment: @JasonB. I agree that this is an exact duplicate. The answers in that question are much more convoluted than they need to be for more recent versions. However, the fact that one can use [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html) directly with the hex code has been added there as well.

Comment: see also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/2079