# How can I define an option "packet" for plots so I can only alter the definition and all plots with that "packet" will change appearance?

Tags: plotting, options

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consistent Plot Styles across multiple MMA files and data sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/consistent-plot-styles-across-multiple-mma-files-and-data-sets)

So, here's my problem; I have a lot of data that is shown in different plots.
I want all the plots to have the same options (`PlotStyle`, `Axes`, `BaseStyle`, `FrameTicks`, etc...).
I also want to be able to modify these options (because the size and `FontSize` change depending on where I want to use the plots, in my thesis or in a presentation) and do that without having to change each `Plot` function by hand.

I guess what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
optionPacket = PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, Frame -> True,
               BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20};
```

and then use it like this:

```
ListPlot[mydata, optionPacket]

ListPlot[mydata2, optionPacket]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? (What I just posted obviously doesn't work or I wouldn't be asking).

Comment: You can define `optionPacket = {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}};` and then do `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> optionPacket]`. Notice your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @freda Welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange! We recommend that you register your account so you can easily keep track of answers and comments to your question. The following question (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/) possibly answers yours.

Comment: Freda, I agree with tkott — this question was asked previously and has received good answers that address your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Sequence[]` for the purpose:

```
optionPacket = Sequence[PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, Frame -> True,
                        BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}]

{ListPlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {7, 2}], optionPacket],
 ListPlot[RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1, 2], {7, 2}], optionPacket]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: list plots]

---

Szabolcs mentions that you can also use a plain list for the purpose, so

```
optionPacket = {PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, Frame -> True,
                BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}}
```

works just as well.

Comment: Actually you can just use a plain `List` of options, there's no need for `Sequence`.  I saw this in the Visualizaion QA and I was a bit surprised it was possible.  Perhaps it's worth mentioning in the answer, it's more newbie-friendly than `Sequence`

Comment: @Szabolcs: Hmm, interesting. I remember a time when one couldn't pass a list of options (which was why the old `FilterOptions[]` produced a `Sequence[]` object as output)...

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work with all functions, but it does seem to work with `Graphics` and several (all?) plotting functions.  `OptionsPattern` and related functions seem to handle it too.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to add your settings to the options :

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}}]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot1]

but

```
ParametricPlot[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot2]