# Making axis numbers larger on Mathematica plot

Tags: plotting, fonts, ticks

I want the numbers along the axis to be larger than the default value.  Can this be done?

The reason I am asking is because I frequently make charts in *Mathematica* and use them in Word.  I export the charts as bitmap files and then paste the images in Word.  The default text size for the axis is too small to be as clearly legible as I would like them to be when the chart is in bitmap form.

My problem would be solved if

- there is a better way to use *Mathematica* charts in Word
- I can get larger text numbers along the axis of the chart .

As an example, the following gives a plot of $\sin(x)$.  How do I make the numbers on the axis larger in size?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 22}, PlotLabel -> Style["sin(x)", FontSize -> 18],
    Background -> LightYellow]
```

Comment: How about adding: `TicksStyle -> FontSize -> 18` or similar? (and I don't use Word)

Comment: Related (and useful): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, TicksStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

For something not quite so big, use:  Larger,
or choose your own font size with:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16]]
```

Edit: Further to @YvesKlett helpful comment, one can even choose different styles for the x and y axes:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, TicksStyle -> {{FontSize -> 16, Orange}, {FontSize -> 22, Green}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The introduction to `Directive` might be even more instructive if used with two arguments, because for just one argument it works just as well without it.