# Forward function arguments to built-in Plot[]

Tags: plotting, function-construction

Suppose I need to write a function to plot the real and imaginary part of some function (just an example). I want to define a function `foo` so that `foo[f[t],{t,0,10},PlotRange->All,(some other plot options)]` essentially calls

```
Plot[{Re[f[t]],Im[f[t]]},{t,0,10},PlotRange->All,(some other plot options)]
```

How to achieve that with, say, pattern matching?

Comment: Does this give what you need: `ClearAll[foo];
SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]; 
foo[f_[t_], {t_, tmin_, tmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Plot[{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, opts]`?

Comment: ... or `foo2 = Plot[{Re[#], Im[#]}, #2, PlotRange -> All, ##3] &;`?

Comment: @kguler thanks, but `foo[Sin[t] + I*Cos[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]` does not work on my machine (output is exactly "foo[Sin[t] + I*Cos[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]").

Comment: @kguler foo2 works perfectly.

Comment: @kguler The foo definition given by @kguler will actually work if you just replace `{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}` with `Evaluate@{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}`. These comments should be posted as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this:

```
SetAttributes[myPlot, HoldAll]

myPlot[x_, args__, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
  Plot[{Re@x, Im@x}, args, opts, PlotRange -> All]
```

Test:

```
myPlot[Sin[t] + I*Cos[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

- [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) is used to mimic the evaluation behavior of `Plot`.
- `OptionsPattern[Plot]` is used to define the valid options as being those of `Plot`.
- `opts` is placed before `PlotRange -> All` so that an explicit `PlotRange` will overrule the default; this is usually desired.

For a longer example of option customization please see:

- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options/358#358)

Also related:

- [Consistent Plot Styles across multiple MMA files and data sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121)

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo = Plot[{Re[#], Im[#]}, #2, PlotRange -> All, ##3] &;

foo[Sin[t] + I*Cos[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: This is terse, and you know I like terse, but there is a problem with it as-written: you lose the `HoldAll` behavior of `Plot` so this will break if e.g. `t` has a global value.