# Unable to import functions from external file

Tags: function-construction

I'm fairly new to Mathematica but I'm in the process of setting up some basic analysis based off someone else's work.  They had a number of shared functions stored in a shared code directory and were using `Get` to import them; however, their code was stored in `.txt` files.  I'd like to replicate that setup but use `.m` files instead to take advantage of Mathematica formatting / debugging, but when I try to import the code from my files the function definitions don't seem to come through.  `Get` isn't returning any errors, but my functions seems to remain undefined (e.g. name in blue, returned as symbolic).  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to link to the files? If not it's hard to debug the problem.

Comment: The basics can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp14opmx0r1x9lc/LoadFunctionTest.zip), thanks!

Comment: perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/why-are-all-the-lines-commented-when-i-create-a-mathematica-script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your files, `expMatrices.m`, looks like this outside *Mathematica*:

[image: file]

You can see that every line is commented out.

If I open this file in *Mathematica*, it looks like this (I've switched the toolbar on):

[image: document using input style]

This looks OK (you can see that only some of the contents are comments, not the whole thing), but the code is in cells that have the **Input** style; for this type of file they should be in **Code** style. To do this, select them, and choose Code from the style menu (or Format>Style>Code):

[image: re-formatted using Code style]

This is now going to work as you expect.

If someone knows a good documentation reference for this not very intuitive design, please add it to this answer. I couldn't find anything particularly informative (except for rm-rf's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/why-are-all-the-lines-commented-when-i-create-a-mathematica-script) that I mentioned in my comment).

Comment: Cells don't really have to be given `Code` style; the cells just need have the property `Initialization Cell`

Comment: Great, thanks so much!