# User defined packages don't load with Needs or Get

Tags: packages

As an introduction to packages in Mathematica I'm following [this short guide](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29325/27539) by Leonid Shifrin, and tried using the sample package provided in that answer. However, both `Needs` and `Get` seem to fail loading the package.

Issuing `Needs` I get the error

```
Needs::nocont: "Context SimpleArithmetic` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
```

Using `Get` I don't get any error, but the package is still not loaded.

Here is what I did (I'm using M10.1 with Windows 7, if that is not obvious from the screenshots :) ):

1. Copy-pasted the code in the answer linked above in a new notebook, saved the notebook with .m extension inside the `$UserBaseDirectory\Applications` folder:

[image]

2. Opened a fresh Mathematica session and used `Needs` to load the package:

[image]

As you can see something is going wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the pointer that Jack gives in his answer is correct, but you can achieve the same effect without using a notebook. Just select all cells in the package file opened in Mathematica as shown in your screenshot and convert everything to code cells (use the menu "Format" -> "Style" -> "Code or just Alt-8). Your code seems to be all in one input cell which is only contained as comment in the package file.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9921/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the SimpleArithmetic.m file and make sure that the code is not commented out.

A technique that works is to name the notebook SimpleArithmetic.nb.

Take the lines that you have copied and make them individual cells (one for each command) rather than a single cell.

Set all of their properties to Initialization Cell. You can select them all (ctrl-A) and set them to Initialization Cell in one fell swoop.

Enable AutoGeneratePackage via:

Format -> Options Inspector -> Notbook Options -> File Options -> AutoGeneratePackage -> **Automatic**.

Make sure that the selection is the current notebook in the above step.

Save the notebook.

A separate file called SimpleArithmetic.m should get created.

Check it with a text editor.

This should work with your `Needs` or `Get` command.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the trick! I didn't really follow your steps though, as for example the AutoGeneratePackage option was greyed out and I couldn't change it. What I did was to verify with a text editor if the code in the generated .m file was commented out as you suggested (and indeed it was). Then I copy-pasted again the code in a new notebook, but before saving it as `.m` file I set the cell (I used a single one) containing the code as an "Initialization Cell". This was enough for the `.m` file to be generated *not* commented out, and `Needs` now works as expected.

Comment: Now however, I'm curious as to where in the documentation is all of this procedure explained. I couldn't find it.

Comment: @glance - Search for AutoGeneratedPackage in the documentation. You will find it there. If it was greyed out I think you need to change the **Show option values** at the top from **Selection** to **Selected Notebook**.