# kernel not running script

Tags: kernel, scripting

I'm on under OS X trying to run a script through the kernel.
My actual plan is to run a bash script which would call mathematica with an address to process a file.
I have finished the code (with precious contributions) and it's working properly.
but when I run it in kernel it accepts it but nothing happens!
I have settled up kernel (in zsh ~/.zshrc ).

```
alias math="/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel"
```

I am using "oh my zsh"

and when I just simply type math kernel runs!

```
Mathematica 10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=
```

but when I type

```
math -script cube_plot.m
```

nothing happens!
(it is supposed to create a jpeg file, I also changed the code to print "something" in case export command doesn't or I dunno??! but still nothing)

I also have another question if I fixed this issue for passing an address to my notebook through script command can I use this

```
math -script cube_plot.m address="/Users/ray/Desktop/Reza/3-1/CMe2/CMe2-t.spindens.cube"
```

Comment: Did you by any chance create `cube_plot.m` using the Mathematica frontend? You may be running into [(9921)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9921).

Comment: I still have the second question, how to pass a variable to mathematica script?

Comment: you can try to run the kernel and input your value, then quit, through bash. The variable should be kept there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of the question, the most likely reason is that the script was created by saving a notebook as a `.m` file from the *Mathematica* frontend. This causes all code to be commented out, except for initialization cells, as described with more detail in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9921) question. Whether this is the case can be verified by opening the `.m` file with a text editor and checking its contents.

For the second part, one can use the `-run` command line option. For example, if the script contains

```
$ cat test.m
Print["Hello, my name is ", name]
```

the following tells the kernel to set the value of `name` in advance

```
$ math -run "name=\"Bob\"" -script test.m
Hello, my name is Bob
```

It is also possible to set an environment variable in the shell, and then read its value with [`GetEnvironment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GetEnvironment.html).