# Script not executed from command line on window

Tags: scripting, command-line

I have a simple test.m file:

```
(*--- file test.m -------*)
Print["Testing"]
Integrate[Sin[x],x]
(*---- end of file ------*)
```

And I executed it in command line (Windows 7 + Mathematica v11.0) like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.0>math < c:\temp\test.m > c:\temp\output.txt
```

No output "Out[n]" was found in the output.txt:

[image: Output.txt]

The .m file is executed fine via the Mathematica Frontend.

Any advise please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, it turns out that all lines are commented as I used the FrontEnd to create the script in input cells and saved it as a package or script file. My actual working file was a notebook hence the package was converted that way (via File->Save as).

I only noticed that when the script was opened via a text editor like notepad, obviously this has been discussed in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/why-are-all-the-lines-commented-when-i-create-a-mathematica-script) question.

IMO, Mathematica shall be able to convert a .nb to .m without commenting, or provide an option in the save as dialog to bypass commenting.

Comment: Cells that are not initialization cells in a notebook are converted to comments when the notebook is saved as a package/script. So, select all the cells you want to be executable and then press Ctrl+8 to turn them into initialization cells.

Comment: Yep, only realized it just now.

In reality, most cells in a notebook are executable except those are commented, then one would think Mathematica would preserve such cells when converting to a package or script.