# GUI->Text code conversion

Tags: code-review, code-organization

I have to solve about 30 symbolic equations simultaneously. *Mathematica* is taking more than 24 hours to solve it on a 6 core system and now I have to run that on a cluster. In order to do so I need to convert GUI based code into text user interface code. Any suggestions how to proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried; `InputForm[HoldForm[your equation here]]`?

Comment: No, I have no knowledge of text user interface code. I have to type few equations and one solve command. How do it do it?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/programmatically-generate-packages-from-notebook-files

Comment: Could you please explain what is "GUI based code" and "text user interface code"? I have been using *Mathematica* for over 10 years and never came across these terms before.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with a Notebook with your complete set of entries in it.
2. Select the Input cells that contain the definitions and commands you wish to run

   - You can select all Input cells by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+clicking the cell bracket of an Input cell
3. Mark the cells as **Initialization Cells** using menu **Cell** > **Cell Properties**
4. Use menu **File** > **Save As...** and save a **Mathematica Package (*.m)**

The `.m` file that you create will contain [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html) expressions for all your definitions and commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing that.. but should it not be in .txt format?

Comment: @Qwerty It is a text format; you could rename .m to .txt if necessary.  However I suggest that you do not as *Mathematica* expects .m and and will use that by default in some cases.  How are you planning to use the contents of the file?  You should be able to `Get` the file directly.