# How to debug an existing notebook in Workbench

Tags: workbench, debugging

I have an existing notebook that I want to debug in workbench. This notebook is a self contained program that does not use any .m files.

From what I can tell from the Workbench documentation you can't really debug a notebook, you have to debug functions that are written in a separate .m file.

As I say my code is all contained within a notebook. I want to use Workbench to create breakpoints in the notebook and trace the value of variables as loops are iterated step by step. Is this possible and if so can someone please explain how.

(I have tried copying my code into a .m file but this doesn't work and any breakpoints I include are ignored.)

Comment: You could convert it to an .m file: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2202/12 (also see the links within).