# Solutions for searching over Mathematica notebooks?

Tags: programming

I have hundreds of Mathematica notebooks accumulated over the years, and I'd like to search over them.

I've been using various versions of text search (grep, SilverSearcher, Spotlight), but there are limitations. For instance, just now I needed to find where I have used the utility function `toc`. Searching for text string `toc[` doesn't work because the raw text in .nb is `RowBox[{"toc", "["`

Older versions of Mathematica offered to install notebook indexing plug-in for Spotlight, but I no longer get this option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `NotebookImport` can import notebooks as plain text, that might be a start.

Comment: The `CreateSearchIndexer`/`TextSearch` approach doesn't seem to work. I have just tried `TextSearch[index, "toc[" ]` and it returns all the files that contain "toc[" *and* all the files that contain only  "toc" without possible distinction.

Comment: The plugin for Spotlight is included in the app bundle.  There is nothing to install separately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert your notebooks to packages as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2223/363):-

```
convert[notebook_, package_] := Module[{nb, str},
  nb = NotebookOpen[notebook, Visible -> False];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  str = First[
    FrontEndExecute[
     FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookSelection[nb], "InputText"]]];
  NotebookClose[nb];
  Export["text.txt", str];
  Quiet[DeleteFile[package]];
  RenameFile["text.txt", package];]
```

Example converting one notebook:

```
convert["notebook.nb", "notebook.m"]
```

Then grep the .m files for `toc[`.