# How to strip out Graphics exported using `FrontEnd`ExportPacket[..., "InputText"]`?

Tags: front-end

I've tried converting 913 Mathematica notebooks I've accumulated over the years into text, and the problem I ran into while using this [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229526/217) is that some files are over 100MBs because they export some output cells with `GraphicsBox` primitives.

Is there an easy work-around to automatically strip out all `GraphicsBox`?

I can't tell if it's a bug or not since `` FrontEnd`ExportPacket `` is not documented, it appears as if `ExportPacket[..., "InputText"]` chooses to convert some output cells. For instance in this [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/blog-laplace-transform-scratch.nb), the first image in an output cell is converted

Some of my [notebooks](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848) have an image in an input cell that was "dragged-and-dropped" in there.