# Coding practice Notebooks vs. Packages: ClearAll?

Tags: packages, development

I have a pretty robust workflow for developing in Notebooks.  One element of that workflow is the reflexive habit of saying `ClearAll` just before a definition so that experimental definitions don't linger and fool me during iterative, interactive development.  For example, suppose I define

```
foo[x_] := bar[x];
```

and then later, I decide to change the definition.  I overwrite the above with

```
foo[xs___] := baz[xs];
```

naively expecting `foo` to forget about `bar`.  But I get a surprise.  While `foo[1, 2]` produces `baz[1, 2]`, `foo[1]` produces the old `bar[1]`.  If I had 
written

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[x_] := bar[x];
```

and

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[xs___] := baz[xs];
```

I wouldn't have had the surprise.  Obviously, this can be really important in big, complex definitions with many cases and branches all intertwined and infeasible to track in your head, so it's a routine habit and I don't even think about it any more.

The question is whether the same habit should pertain to Package development.  I never see `ClearAll` before definitions in the Packages I've read, but wouldn't it make sense for the same reason as it does in Notebooks?  Or is there some other development fu technique that I don't know about for Packages?  Or do people only publish completely finished, formally certified & debugged Packages, and they never need to do iterative development on them ever again (tiny sarcasm)?  Or, is there special magic in the Package system that clears symbols on a package reload?  Perhaps the subcontexts are automatically discarded?

In short, why don't I see ubiquitous `ClearAll` in Packages?

Comment: In packages, all symbols should be localized to the package context, then you can clear the whole context in one go instead of having to clear definitions one by one.  Some packages have it at the beginning.

Comment: FWIW, I keep `ClearAll` in my packages, even in production code. I can't see how this can possibly hurt, while this leaves me an option to *not* clear certain symbols, for example because they receive their definitions in more than one file (which doesn't often happen, but sometimes does, and can not always be easily avoided).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using [automatically generated packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1369/121) I am selective about which Cells I mark for Initialization and therefore transference to the package file.  I don't find the need to include `ClearAll` in such cases.  I do use a `Unprotect` / `Protect` paring which at least prevents additional definitions from accidentally being made elsewhere.

A case where `ClearAll` might be undesirable is memoization; one may want to be able to forcefully reload the package (`Get`) without losing existing memoized values.  (This contravenes direct use of `Protect` however.)

Comment: If I read your first paragraph correctly, you're exercising a Package-development fu technique where you develop in Notebooks, create packages by automatic generation (reference, please?), and seldom if ever edit the `.m` package file directly?

Comment: @Reb.Cabin That is correct.  Let me see what documentation I can find.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin For documentation I linked to a question, which I just realized *you* asked.  There is also [(2202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2202/121).

Comment: LOL -- i guess there are many kinds of leaks -- evaluation leaks, resource leaks, MEMORY leaks :)

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I've got *a lot* of memory leaks myself.  I fear I am at risk of forgetting my own name sometimes.

Comment: I wonder how you added an invisible link to this page.  I see the underlined (2202), which corresponds to one of the links in the list of links in the right-hand column just below the add rectangle, but I don't see an underlined clicky in the other part of the page page corresponding to the other link in the list of links :)  How do you add something to that list of links?

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I believe you will find that the link in my answer "automatically generated packages" points to one question and (2202) to the other.  I originally had the link in my answer pointing to (2202) but quickly found 1369 (as it is linked from 2202) and updated it to point to that instead.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Not only forgetful am I, but blind, too :)

Answer (score 4):

I found, in the "Applications" section of the documentation of `ClearAll`, this authoritative recommendation:

> Unprotect and clear all symbols in a package, to allow it to be read
>   twice:

```
Begin["`Private`"];

Unprotect["`*"]; 
ClearAll["`*"];

f[x_] := x^2

Protect[f];

End[];
```

I don't see this advice in the guide [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html) for Setting up Wolfram Packages, which seems a small shame.

Comment: I cannot recall reading that, but I probably have.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.  I do not necessarily read that line as commanding, but declarative, explaining the code below.  A somewhat odd example though as I don't believe the `ClearAll` will change anything there.

Comment: Wouldn't the `ClearAll` have the declared effect if the package were read in twice?  By the way, somewhere in the Wolfram docs there was a package example with ``Begin["Private`"]`` instead of ``Begin["`Private`"]``, which would seem to cause all kinds of mayhem (crosstalk amongst packages).  I couldn't find it again, else I would have written an SE question about it.

Comment: What I meant is that only in select cases will `ClearAll` actually be needed; normally evaluating the definition code *again* on top of the existing definitions usually works just fine.  In this case you can run `Do[f[x_] := x^2, {1000}]` and it's just the same when it gets done.  It would have been better, IMHO, to give an example where the `ClearAll` was *needed* and without it the definitions failed.  Although now that I'm writing this I suppose it would be "good practice" to throw in a `ClearAll` just in case.

Comment: I see.  Yes, the `ClearAll` is most useful during development when one is rapidly changing the *architecture* of an API --- the various patterns you want your rules to match.  That's where you get bitten by the implicit system-rules that can reorder your rules, and your lingering rules that don't get eliminated when you broaden or sharpen patterns.