# Communication between notebooks

Tags: notebooks

Imagine I have 2 notebooks with the following contents:

Notebook 1: "notebook1.nb"

```
a1 = 1;

f1[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;

Print[f2[2, 1]];
```

Notebook 2: "notebook2.nb"

```
a2 = 2;

f2[x_, y_] := x - y;

Print[f1[1, 2, 3]];

Print[a1 + a2];
```

What do I have to do that the notebooks can share variables and functions with each other?

Comment: Notebooks do share all definitions by default.  Make sure that Evaluation -> Notebook's Kernel is Local and Notebook's Default Context is Global. These are the defaults, and it should be like this unless you changed them yourself.

Comment: But what is if I would only open notebook1.nb and not notebook2.nb. Is it possible to import/include somehow the content and definitions, like in other languages.

Comment: I think that is a completely different question ... Use packages, not notebooks.  Notebooks are for interactive work: they are meant to be opened and evaluated manually.  Packages are meant to be loaded using a command (i.e. programmatically).  "Package" here means: put everything into a plain text file with an `.m` (or `.wl`) extension and load it using `Get`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Can you show a simple example how to start?

Comment: There isn't anything to show really ... enter those commands into a text file, not a notebook. Save the file as `something.m`.  To evaluate all expressions in the file, use `Get["something.m"]` (you may need to specify the full path).

Comment: If you want to use the front end as you editor, start with File -> New -> Package (and not File -> New -> Notebook)

Comment: Once you are comfortable with doing this, take a look here as well: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1369/12  Also, if you strongly prefer notebooks, it *is* possible to evaluate them programmatically using `NotebookEvaluate` (since version 10.0, I think).  But I still maintain that plain text `.m` files are much better for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much. This Infos helps me a lot.

Comment: Try doing evaluations without `Print`. You will find that you don't need `Print`