# How to use external Mathematica Code?

Tags: functions, programming

I have a Mathematica Notebook with a function that i would like to be able to access from another Notebook without having to have the first Notebook open. The functions calls other functions in the same notebook so all code in that nootebook would have to be compiled. Thanks for any help in advance!!

Comment: Put the definitions not in a notebook, but a plain text file (a "package file"), then load it using `Get`.  You may find auto-generated packages useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/how-to-make-a-parallel-auto-generated-m-package-from-initialization-cells

Comment: Take a look also at [Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/5478), does information from those links fit your needs?

Comment: I just wanted to note that it is not strictly necessary to create a "proper package" with `BeginPackage`, etc. `Get`ing a file will simply evaluate everything in that file. It's as if you had evaluated a notebook.

Comment: What about those: [1959](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1959/5478), [11945](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11945/5478)

Comment: Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there is another, newer, way to store definitions that may suit your purposes: to store then as local objects (or even as cloud objects), then retrieve them when needed. I'll illustrate with a very simple example and just for local objects.

In a notebook session, evaluate successively:

```
    def = "func[x_]:=Exp[-x]Sin[x]"
    LocalObject["file:///Users/myname/Desktop/funcdef"]
    Put[def, %]
```

Then at any subsequent *Mathematica* session, in any notebook, evaluate...

```
    Get[LocalObject["file:///Users/myname/Desktop/funcdef"]]
    ToExpression[%]
```

...and see that it works:

```
    func[\[Pi]/4]
E^(-\[Pi]/4)/Sqrt[2]
```

Comment: Why not `Save/Get` from a file directly? Is there any advantage of using LocalObject? There has to be a good one if one is expect to write their definitions as strings and use ToExpression later.

Comment: @Kuba: I'm just pointing out an alternative there; no claim of advantage, although there may be one -- especially if you use a `CloudObject` rather than a `LocalObject`.